# Django Lightsail - attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my Djago app on AWS Lightsail.

When I try to login/register, I am getting this error:

> Attempt to write a readonly database

I have been googling solutions for quite some time and have tried setting different permissions, even giving away all permissions which might be huge security risk, however it still doesn't work.

Could anyone help me.

Comment: Seems like the problem isn't the permissions of the user that Django uses to access the database, the problem seems to be that the database itself is in a read-only state. Can you execute an update or insert statement on this database using another client?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what do you mean execute update/insert using another client, but strange thing is that when I start development server and access page via <public_up>:8000, it all works correctly. When I use production server with my custom domain, it doesn't work. Also, I'm looking into using postgres right now, as it looks like it's better for production. But I do not really have idea about that either as I'm beginner and this is the first real django deployment, but it's just one problem after another

Comment: Well, Django tries to insert/update stuff in your database, right? What kind of database is it, and with what type of tool (some client program, like SSMS for SQL Server, of web client like PHPMyAdmin) do you do admin on the database? Can you insert/update anything in the Django DB with that tool?

Comment: I'm using the default db.sqlite3 and haven't used any client program. I can insert into DB using django shell for example, or when I use the development server. Since it doesn't work on my real domain, I assume it has to do something with permissions for the domain, it's really confusing. Too many things to manage for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

check that your file is owned by bitnami:bitnami. (I've been having the same exact issue and yours and i havent been able to fix it either)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I check that? I'm giving it full permissions but it just won't work..

Comment: so basically do a sudo chown bitnami:bitnami  db.sqlite3 . Also if you're having trouble visit my thread from the bitnami community ( https://community.bitnami.com/t/permissions-on-db-sqlite3/88600?u=visitprakhar ). I've been trying to get my issue fixed as well and you can participate in the thread as well

Comment: So, looks like a "fixed" this one - what helped was moving db.sqlite to outside directory of project it self. In settings.py I just changed location to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'db.sqlite3'). I assume this is full of security holes also db itself remains on 777, but it's just so frustrating I don't care anymore. Now I'm dealing with yet another problem, but at least db is working now

Comment: HEY IT WORKS THANK YOU SOO MUCH!!!! I'VE BEEN HAVING THIS ISSUE FOR A MONTH BUT NOW ITS FINALLY SOLVED THAMK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Haha, I'm glad. I should post this as an answer if someone else needs. There's something other as well that helped me. Well, I did few changes so not really sure if this one was the key, but in apache2 main conf file, there is general user mentioned (daemon) and I changed this one to my user and that allowed me to actually change permission rules on DB so it should be more secure. Honestly, it might be super unstable my deployment after all these changes I had to go through, but at this point I'm satisfied with just having the app finally online. Time to look into linux too, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for answering me in caps cause that's exactly how I felt after 5 days, not to mention one month ;D

Comment: So you changed the user from daemon to bitnami? Did you keep the group the same? also what permissions did you put on your db.sqlite3 file?

Comment: I'm asking because i still get that password breach popup thing from my browser, despite shifting to a 664 permission status

Comment: well I changed more things so can not really say which one was it, but I think I changed it to www-data (I read somewhere www-data is the server making requests to django) and then I changed db.sqlite3 to be owned by bitnami but group www-data with 664 permissions. I don't know these linux permisisons are complete mess

Comment: Well, I hope it works out for you. The bitnami stack developers have managed to reproduce this very issue at their end, and are investigating it. I'll let you know if I find a more robust solution and I hope you will do the same too!

Comment: Cool, they should look into it cause most likely it's some kind of bug. If only few users run into it and can't fix it no matter what

Answer (score 0):

So, in case someone else has this problem, what should work and what worked for me:

**I moved db.sqlite3 file to one folder outside of main project dir**.

Then I changed address to this file in settings.py to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'db.sqlite3')

Though I feel like it's really a problem of user permissions, but that's above my current skill level.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that worked for me.

See: https://github.com/mchesler613/django_adventures/blob/main/deploy_django_aws_bitnami.md

Author goes into detail about the details behind the error.
See "Error: Attempt to write a readonly database"

---

Change group ownership of the project root directory and the database file to daemon. For example:

`$ sudo chgrp daemon project_directory project_directory/database_file`

Make the project root directory and the database file writable by the daemon group. For example:

`$ sudo chmod g+w project_directory project_directory/database_file`

To see if the database error goes away, try reloading the Django app on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing db.sqlite3 mode to writable doesn't work for me. I can use django shell to add data to db.sqlite3 but from apache2, it doesn't work.

Finally, I changed owner of the directory where db.sqlite3 locates to www-data:www-data, and it worked.